# Running Flex 4 on AIR 1.5.3

Tags: apache-flex, macos, air

I'm trying to migrate a large project to Flex 4.
The problem is that the AIR version must be compatible with old MACs (without intel processors) such as G5. As far as I know, only AIR runtime 1.5.3 works on these machines, but Flex 4 requires AIR 2.0.

Is there any possible way to deploy an AIR application built with Flex 4 components on these MACs?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hi
I do not think it is an option for you to use the new Flex 4 components, but if you just stick with the "old" mx component set, you should be able to use the latest revision of the framework if not for anything else, then at least to benefit from the latest bug-fixes.

You can try and have a look here as well: [Upgrading Flex 3/AIR Projects to Gumbo/Flex 4](http://richardleggett.co.uk/blog/index.php/2009/02/12/upgrading_flex_3_air_projects_to_gumbo_f_4)

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

No.  Flex 4 requires the Flash Player 10 APIs which were added in AIR 2.